# Canvas pinch zoom like Snapseed android app

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, zooming

I'm wondering on how to make something like the zoom in the canvas of Snapseed android app.

Is it an ImageView with zooming, or is it Custom View and how to make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how snapseed is doing. I was working on an app where you can upload image onto a canvas and apply zooming and panning on that image. By extending the **ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener** Class in your View or custom view and overriding the **onScale()** method. You can set the scale factor inside this method.

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override

    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));

        return true;

    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am a beginner programmer, this code is not as smooth and professional as I would like to get. Is there anyway to make it smooth ?